# how simply get children of children entities with EF and LINQ in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

Probably i'm getting lost in a noproblem, but I can't find a easy solution for this:

I have an entity "CUSTOMER"

that have a virtual icollection of "ORDER" called ORDERS

that have a virtual icollection of "ITEM" called ITEMS.

How to get all item bouht by my customer in any order?

something like:

```
icollection<item> allitem = mycustomer.orders.items;
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 IEnumerable<Item> allItems = myCustomer.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.Items);
```

Comment: thankyou very mutch... it was exactly what I was looking for. My main problem was i was using ICollection instead IEnumerable.